# how to check response of stripe transaction using simple form and js

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway, stripe-payments, payment-processing

I am trying to setup [stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) checkout and i can get the payment form up and running just fine, however i need to redirect the user to another page only after payment has been successfull. This is the javascript I am using to display the form and to process it but I need to know how and where can i add the code of redirect?

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<button id="customButton" style="border: none" ><img src="/orange_pay_now.png" style="width: 265px;height: 66px;"></button>
<script>
    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: 'pk_test_..............',
        image: '/orange_pay_now.png',
        token: function(token) {
            // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
            // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // Open Checkout with further options
        handler.open({
            name: 'Name of Product',
            description: 'description goes here',
            amount: 800,
            currency: 'GBP'
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Close Checkout on page navigation
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
        handler.close();
    });
</script>
```

I will really appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout should be created within the context of another form on that page (see the simple integration):

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout

When Checkout completes its thing, it'll automatically submit that other form to whatever `action` attribute you use. Then you can use your server-side code to process an actual charge request.

If you're using a custom integration, you'll instead want to add code to the token function to submit your form or redirect the browser or whatever.

Hope that helps,
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.